# File upload value change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wish to change the file upload value when the file name (uploaded file) is too long. For example, if the file name is "This_file_has_a_long_name.txt", I wish to display it with limited characters like "This_file..name.txt".

So I tried the following but it is not working. Please advise.

```
$("#file_browser").change(function()
{
  var filename = this.value;
  filename = filename.substr(0,10);
  alert(filename);
  document.getElementById("file_browse").value = filename;
});
```

Comment: It is not working how? What is the expected outcome here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**Note:if length of name be 14 and greater , change it.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        
        $("#file_browser").change(function() {
    
            var filename = $(this).val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
            //Or for full path use, var filename = $(this).val();
            
            var len = filename.length;
            
            if (len <= 13 ) {
                
                $("#file_browse").text(filename);
                
            }
            
            else {
                
                var part1 = filename.substr(0,5);
                var part2 = filename.substr(len - 8);
                 $("#file_browse").text(part1 + "..." + part2);
                
            }
                
        })
        
})
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file_browser">
<p id="file_browse"></p>
        
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant change a property name in js cause of security normaly you will have 
a msg `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.`

if you want you do that you need its to hide the default input file css go to google for that you have tuto
and add your filname custom in a `<p></p>` for exemple and place where you want

if you really need to change name do that on server side

good day

Answer (score 0):

What about some trick.

JS

```
$("#file_browse").change(function()
{
    var data = $(this).val();
    $(this).val();
    data = data.replace(/(.{1,10}).{1,}(.{6})/,"$1..$2");
    $("#file_browse").after("<div style='position:absolute; top:4px;  margin-left:230px;'>"+data+"</div>");

});
```

The add the following css

```
input[type=file]
{ 
        color:transparent;
}
```

Adjust the margin-left and top position.

Store the filename into the variable `data`.

Then make an empty field by using `$(this).val();` So your input type file label contain like `No file choose` are some thing like, this is because of to avoid your input file name is so long means scroll will appear.

Use the pattern replace for include dots.

Then make the div tag for write the filename.

Don't forgot to add the css for transparent file text color.

Answer (score -1):

You better use the `name` property to get just the file name and hide the default file input because you can't change its value.

```js
$("#fileInput").change(function () {
  if (this.files.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  
  var name = this.files[0].name;
  
  if (name.length > 14) {
    name = name.substr(0, 7) + "..." + name.substr(-7);
  }
  
  $("#fileNameText").text(name);
});

$("#chooseButton").click(function () {
  $("#fileInput").click();
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display: none" />
  <button type="button" id="chooseButton">Choose file</button>
  <span id="fileNameText">Select a file</span>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```